# Data Fusion Public IP Address

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

Do you know if it is possible to allocate a dedicated public IP address to a Data Fusion instance? In order to connect to some databases (not hosted on GCP) I need to whitelist the public IP address first. I tried looking into the documentation, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

The Datafusion instance is not accessible to the customer. The only approach is for data fusion to go "through" the customer project. This maybe helpful https://medium.com/@ammppp/using-haproxy-with-cloud-data-fusion-to-navigate-complex-network-topologies-fb3765bdbb2f

You can also look at the section on "Connect to an external source" here https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/create-private-ip. This may be useful as well https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/egress-control

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to connect with the external databases. Example: running a pipeline in Datafusion depends on the compute profile, you can use a compute profile with an existing cluster, the dataproc cluster can either be public and workers have public IP addresses or private cluster using Cloud NAT where you can assigned static IP addresses. Since dataproc runs in your project , you have control over the connectivity.

In developer edition or fetching schema etc from datafusion console, you can use a VM acting as a proxy (using iptables etc) and control the connectivity as well.